# Moving the picture captured to the next activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-imageview, android-image

Am trying to put the picture captured by the user in the second activity. Every time I capture the picture it takes me to the nextActivity but the problem am facing now is how to put the image captured inside the next activity so the user can see it

Please any one can guide me or direct me on how should i do it?

This is my code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAM_REQUEST) {

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

           Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            Intent i = new Intent(this, PostActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("name", thumbnail);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code to send data through Intent

```
        Intent intent=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("imagepath",path);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Code To Receive Data that sent through Intent in SecondActivity

```
        Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
        String path=b.getString("imagepath");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an image path to intent extras and get it in the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

Send Image URI using Intent Extras in between Activities.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("uri",uri);
                        startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you Receive `Bitmap` on `onActivityResult` method. so you can try with following code to pass image to the`NextActivity`.

1) Convert `Bitmap` to Byte Array

```
Bitmap mBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

// Pass it to intent to send in NextActitivy
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("captured_image", byteArray);
startActivity(intent);
```

2) Get byte from bundle on `NextActivity` at `onCreate()` method

```
Bundle mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
byte[] mBytes = mBundle.getByteArray("captured_image");

Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mBytes, 0, mBytes.length);
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

mImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
```

Comment: in this line intent.putExtra("captured_image", byteArray); --- can i put any name i want instead of "captured_image" ?

Comment: @MazinAlmaskari you can take any name but it must be same while you send from onActivityResult method and fetch it on NextActivity. :)

Comment: thanks.. am still facing the problem.. can you check my code in the post and point to me where am doing wrong pls.. this code is in my mainActivity

Comment: and what should i write in my secondActivity

Comment: about the second step you wrote.. i should do it on the onCreate() method right? :) sorry for asking too much

Comment: @MazinAlmaskari Yes you should call it at `onCreate()` method on Activity. and sorry for late was afk. and not an issue you can ask. :)